# How to overcome issue 500 (The backend responded with an error) in consul?

Tags: consul

Hi on my macbook I am using consul version 1.8.0

and with this config I launch (`consul agent  -config-file desky.json`):

```
{
 "node_name": "desky.local",
 "ui": true,
 "retry_join": ["172.20.20.31"],
 "advertise_addr": "172.20.20.1",
 "data_dir": "/tmp/consul"
}
```

I know this issue is reported here but it seems people are still having issue and not reply of it having fixed. https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/7288

in the commandline of my macbook where I run consul agent I get the following log with some errors right at the launch.

```
 2020-08-31T18:04:17.048+0100 [INFO]  agent: Retry join is supported for the following discovery methods: cluster=LAN discovery_methods="aliyun aws azure digitalocean gce k8s linode mdns os packet scaleway softlayer tencentcloud triton vsphere"
    2020-08-31T18:04:17.048+0100 [INFO]  agent: Joining cluster...: cluster=LAN
    2020-08-31T18:04:17.048+0100 [INFO]  agent: started state syncer
==> Consul agent running!
    2020-08-31T18:04:17.048+0100 [INFO]  agent: (LAN) joining: lan_addresses=[172.20.20.31]
    2020-08-31T18:04:17.048+0100 [WARN]  agent.client.manager: No servers available
    2020-08-31T18:04:17.048+0100 [ERROR] agent.anti_entropy: failed to sync remote state: error="No known Consul servers"
    2020-08-31T18:04:17.051+0100 [INFO]  agent.client.serf.lan: serf: EventMemberJoin: consul-server 172.20.20.31
    2020-08-31T18:04:17.051+0100 [INFO]  agent.client: adding server: server="consul-server (Addr: tcp/172.20.20.31:8300) (DC: dc1)"
    2020-08-31T18:04:17.051+0100 [INFO]  agent: (LAN) joined: number_of_nodes=1
    2020-08-31T18:04:17.051+0100 [INFO]  agent: Join cluster completed. Synced with initial agents: cluster=LAN num_agents=1
    2020-08-31T18:04:18.584+0100 [ERROR] agent.client: RPC failed to server: method=Catalog.NodeServiceList server=172.20.20.31:8300 error="rpc error making call: rpc: can't find method Catalog.NodeServiceList"
    2020-08-31T18:04:18.591+0100 [INFO]  agent: Synced node info
    2020-08-31T18:04:19.476+0100 [INFO]  agent: Newer Consul version available: new_version=1.8.3 current_version=1.8.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, Hashicorp should address this as an possible example when the error is thrown,

I used this on the consul server side :

```
-bind 0.0.0.0
-client 0.0.0.0
```

that fixed this issue.

Comment: Hi Ciasto, based on this change I suspect that the Consul server was not listening on the appropriate IP addresses to allow clients to join the cluster. I recommend reviewing the Consul's [Common Error Messages](https://www.consul.io/docs/common-errors) and [Troubleshoot Common Consul Issues](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/troubleshooting?in=consul/datacenter-operations) pages to see if the error you encountered in the logs is captured there. If not, we can consider adding this to the documentation.

Comment: well, its actually not covered in the common error messages. I checked for "rpc error making call"
`consul operator raft list-peers
Error getting peers: Failed to retrieve raft configuration: Unexpected response code: 500 (rpc error making call: No cluster leader)`

Comment: See this doc for info on properly bootsrapping a data center https://www.consul.io/docs/install/bootstrapping, and ensuring a leader gets elected. As mentioned at the bottom of the page "most operations will fail until the servers are available."